# Batch file to move folders starting with specific name to a new created folder

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

I've made a batch to move files starting with a specific name to new created folders but i can't find a solution to do the same with folders.
I have folders
RLW-1
RLW-2
RLW-3

and i want to move all the above folders to a new created folder named "RLW" using a batch file.
I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
mkdir "C:/Users/%USERNAME%/Desktop/Photos/RLW"
move "C:/Users/%USERNAME%/Desktop/Photos/RLW*" "C:/Users/%USERNAME%/Desktop/Photos/RLW"
```

This only creates the "RLW" folder but doesn't move the others in it. 
(Windows 10)

Comment: `cmd`uses ``\`` not ``/`` in directory names.

Comment: Tried with "\" but no change.

Comment: You can't use `*` when moving folders. You can use it only for files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wildcard `*` will only move files not folders. You need to list all the folders starting with RLW- and then move them one by one.

```
move "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Photos\RLW*" "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Photos\RLW"

for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b /s /a:d "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Photos\RLW-*"') do move %%G C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\Photos\RLW
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! I can't thank you enough Reddy!